# Traversing a maze from one cell to another

Tags: matrices, algorithms, puzzle

I have maze (10*10) as shown below:

[image]

Each cell has unique value ranging from [0,15] which actually defines its walls (see the image below). For example, value of first cell (r=0, c=0) is 7 and so on.

[image]

Now I need to travel from entry point to exit point. Entry point is always at the left side of maze which is created by removing any wall. Same is done on the right side of maze where the exit is. These points will be provided by indicating with an arrow in the image.

I know how we actually traverse from one point to another inside rectangular grid. It contains values in binary form where $1$ signify block to that cell and $0$ signify that path is possible from that cell.

PS: You will be only provided a 10*10 matrix with values filled accordingly and you will need to get row and column number as a path from entry point to exit point.

Comment: If there is a solution (there will be in your example because it is a tree) then one algorithm is to walk round keeping your hand on the left-hand wall until you reach the exit

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve a general maze is to view it as a tree with two special vertices, a start and an end, and we need to find the unique simple path that connects them.

Define the start and end vertices as at least degree 2 by adding an edge to the 'outside'.

Any terminal vertices (degree 1) can all be removed, as it is impossible for them to be in the path.

This leaves a new tree, and again we can remove all of the terminal vertices.

This process leaves only the solution path between Start and End.

In your case, repeatedly replace all cells that are $7, 11, 13, 14$ with $15$ and recalculate the cell values.